# how to build static program with gccgo

Tags: go, static, gccgo

I has a prblem when  I use gccgo to build static programe version

1> use go build
go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-static -L/lib64' test.go
result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

2>use gccgo build
gccgo -o test_gccgo_yes -static -L/lib64 test.go
result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

3> if I don't use static to compile it 
gccgo -o test_gccgo_yes -g test.go
result :
ldd test_gccgo_yes 
show test_gccgo_yes is dynamic file

How I can build static program with gccgo?

Comment: Show the code of the program you're trying to compile. For a simple hello world program `go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags "-static" hello.go` works for me.

Comment: An error like "cannot find -lpthread" implies that you do not have the static version of the pthread library on your system.  You need to have libpthread.a somewhere, such as /usr/lib or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.  If you don't, you need to install it.  That may also be the problem with libgo; it depends on how you installed gccgo.

Comment: package main 
 
//import "os"// 用于获得命令行参数os.Args 
import "fmt" 
//import "strconv" 

func main() {
 var a = "asdf" 
 const(
 c0=iota
 c1=iota
 c2=iota
 )
 var v_111 int 
 v_111 = 111 
 fmt.Println("complex dsf ", v_111) 
    fmt.Printf("Result: %d %d %d %s\n", c0, c1, c2, a) 
 var str string
 str = "hello world"
 for i :=0; i< len(str); i++{
  fmt.Println(i, str[i])
 }
 //array
  ar_b :=[5] byte{1,2,3,4,15}
 for _ , v :=range ar_b{
  fmt.Println(v, " ")
 } 
}

Comment: I use -L/lib64 in build command line to set the library search path, because there are all lib files on this dir

Comment: ps why I set -L/lib64  because:
ldd test_gccgo_yes 

        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8e9fe000)

        libgo.so.4 => /lib64/libgo.so.4 (0x00007fd4bf2f0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd4befee000)

        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd4bedd7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd4bea16000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd4c0023000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd4be7fa000)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `static` then gccgo requires the static versions of each library i.e. `libc.a` rather than the dynamic libs `libc.so`.

Install your distro's static packages. On CentOS 7, they are named `glibc-static` and `libgo-static`. Then you should be able to build (you won't need the `-L` flag either)

However, you may still get some warnings and possibly errors after that. For example when building one such static application I got these errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgo.a(net.o): In function `net.lookupPort':
(.text+0x48e2): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
```

So more work may be required to get a working static binary. See https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/no_static_linking.html